# ¿Como pasar variables de PHP a jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

```
<?php 
$consulta = "SELECT idPais FROM pais";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
     $pais = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idPais']);
     ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(cargar);
            function cargar(){
                var paisJq = "<?php echo $pais ?>";

$('#categoria').append('<option      value="paisJq">document.write("VariableJS = " + paisJq);</option>');

$('option',this).click(function(){
                    var valor=$(this).text();
                    alert(valor);
                });
            }
        </script>

<?php    
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Amigo, no se entiende lo que preguntas. No trates de explicar todo en el título. Usa el contenido de tu pregunta para explayarte sobre lo que quieres obtener y cómo estás intentando obtenerlo (esa parte ya la pusiste)

Comment: #categoria es un select?

Comment: Si cateegoria es un SELECT y lo quiero poner como un SELECT Multiple usando los datos almacenados en la BD

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar, no tiene sentido usar `document.write` dentro de un `append` de `jQuery`. Tienes que usar el operador `+` para concatenar texto.

Segundo, tampoco tiene sentido hacer una función para añadir un option si los parámetros están definidos mediante un `echo`.

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
    include('configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>
<script>
  jQuery('document').ready(function() {

  <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idPais FROM pais";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $pais = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idPais']);
  ?>
       var paisJq= <?php echo $pais ?>;
       $('#categoria').append('<option value="'+ paisJq +'" >VariableJS = ' + paisJq +');</option>');
  <?php  
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
  ?>

    $('option').click(function(){
      var valor=$(this).text();
      alert(valor);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Ojo, que según tu pregunta, #categoria es un DIV y no un SELECT.

Comment: Hice una corrección en el código, ya que había un error JS.

Comment: Gracias amigo ahora se corre bien, solo te falto poner las comillas a la variable de php, el resto esta de maravilla, ahora buscare darle click y que me almacene ese mismo dato a otro div ( tipo Filtro ), si tienes un pequeño aporte te lo aradeceria amigo